# multiprocessing VS multithreading, which better for reading & then writing data

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I've a large text file **(3.7GB)** contains **300,000,000** lines. I should read **every** line, process it, append it to another text file, so Which is better multiprocessing or multithreading and **why**?
I need to complete process it as much faster as can.

**EDITED: I use python3**

Comment: What does "process it" actually mean here?

Comment: I am assuming that you mean distributed processing for multiprocessing, is that correct?

Comment: Is this a one time activity? or its going to be repeated and re-used? Can we expect more and bigger files in future?

Comment: `multiprocessing` doesn't need to be distributed processing, it's a [module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process)

Comment: I mean take that line & add some text to it, or do somthing else, then append it to another file text., and repeat it

Comment: So, is there any way to do it better and shorter time?

Comment: "Spawning processes is a bit slower than spawning threads. Once they are running, there is not much difference."  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

Comment: What specific part are you trying to achieve using another process/thread ? e.g. Appending it to other file.. is it just to make sure you processed that line.. than you can go with file offset. If you create multiprocess or multithread you also have to deal with how to pass data between them. Threads are lighter to create less overhead on system. But i guess you need to edit your post to provide more details.